# createSQLException Error while in Configuring Data Source with Weblogic

Tags: java, mysql, weblogic, datasource, ejb-3.0

I am trying to configure DataSources with WebLogic 10.3 and database is MySQL Server 5.5 , On entering the following

Driver Class Name      ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

url                    =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/weblogicdb

Database User Name     =root (User name of Database MySql Server)

Password               =123(Password name of Database MySql Server)

Confirm Password       =123

and on clicking TestConfiguration, I get the following error.

```
    Connection test failed.

    Message icon - Error Unknown database 'weblogicdb'<br/>com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:930)
    <br/>com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2864)
    <br/>com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:806)
    <br/>com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3263)
    <br/>com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1176)
    <br/>com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2638)
    <br/>com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1525)
    <br/>com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:260)
    <br/>com.bea.console.utils.jdbc.JDBCUtils.testConnection(JDBCUtils.java:505)
    <br/>com.bea.console.actions.jdbc.datasources.createjdbcdatasource.CreateJDBCDataSource.testConnectionConfiguration(CreateJDBCDataSource.java:369)
    <br/>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)<br/>sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    <br/>sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)<br/>java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    <br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
    <br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
    <br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
    <br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
    <br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
    <br/>org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)<br/>...
```

I was looking into many blogs and previously asked questions, where they it could be because of username and password being incorrect. But that is not the issue in my case, I have rechecked it. on using the same username and password, I was able to log into my MySQL database.

Kindly help me in configuring the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error stack clearly says that:

> Message icon - Error Unknown database '`weblogicdb`'

It seems you have input a wrong database name.

You might be succeeding with username/passwords to MySQL server.
But the server might have multiple databases in it and '`weblogicdb`' is not the correct database name you are trying to connect to.

To see what databases the MySQL Server has in it, execute the following command either using `java` or any other MySQL clients like MySQL command line, SQLyog, PHPMyAdmin etc.

```
show databases();
```

This statement should result all the databases available.
Identify the appropriate one for your program and use the same in your code.

To connect through `java` to execute the above statement, db url should be:

```
url =jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?user=usernamevalue&password=passwordvalue
```

Comment: Oh, Thank you. I was never knowing that. In-fact I had not created one thank you.